# PEGJS : Nested pegjs grammar

Tags: javascript, peg, pegjs

```
start
  = intExp

intExp
  = andIntExp
  / orIntExp

andIntExp 
   = integer (andExp intExp)*

orIntExp 
   = integer (orExp intExp)*

andExp 
  = space* "and" space* { return "and";}

orExp 
  = space* "or" space*  { return "or";}

space 
  = [\n \t]

integer "integer"
  = digits:[0-9]+ { return parseInt(digits.join(""), 10); }
```

I want to parse input like

`2 or 2 or 2` or `2 and 2 and 2` but `2 or 2 and 2` is invalid. In short I dont want `and` and `or` to occur together within the input. Is there any way to do this with peg, without involving javascript and storing previously seen variable (For which I already have a solution) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Parsing expression grammars are deterministic. They try the first match and fail on first mismatch, also, they don't backtrack. You can just negate ambiguous expressions and your grammar will work as expected:

```
Start
  = IntExpr

IntExpr
  = OrIntExpr
  / AndIntExpr

OrIntExpr
  = Integer _ !"and" ("or" _ OrIntExpr)?

AndIntExpr
  = Integer _ ("and" _ AndIntExpr)?

Integer "integer"
  = digits:[0-9]+ { return parseInt(digits.join(""), 10); }

_ "space"
  = [\n \t]*
```

Our `OurExpr` refuses matching if receives `and` and jumps to the next option.

The following rules have been tested:

`1 and 2 and 3` => `PASS`

`1` => `PASS`

`4 or 2 or 1` => `PASS`

`9 and 2 or 3` => `FAIL`

Comment: Thanks Marcelo for the solution. It works, your are right.